# Unknown property geometry while generating gltfjsx component

Tags: reactjs, blender, react-three-fiber, gltf, react-three-drei

I have a gltf exported from blender, and i am using react three fiber, three, react-three/drei and react-three/fiber and gltfjsx.

I am generating a jsx component with gltfjsx library by running

```
`npx gltfjsx public/room.gltf`
```

The issue is that the component generated is full of errors.

Mainly the error i get is `Unknown property geometry`

The following is a fragment of my component:

```
/*
Auto-generated by: https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx
Command: npx gltfjsx@6.2.13 ../public/room.gltf --transform 
Files: ../public/room.gltf [466.14KB] > room-transformed.glb [197.46KB] (58%)
*/

import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei'

export function Model(props) {
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/room-transformed.glb')
  return (
    <group {...props} dispose={null}>
      <mesh geometry={nodes.Cube004.geometry} material={materials.PaletteMaterial001} position={[0, 4, 0]} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.Torus.geometry} material={nodes.Torus.material} position={[-2.689, 1.707, -1.732]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={[0.059, 0.079, 0.059]} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.Plane009.geometry} material={materials.PaletteMaterial002} position={[-0.789, 2.913, -5.122]} rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={[0.474, 0.474, 0.965]} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.Cube063.geometry} material={materials.PaletteMaterial003} position={[-3.924, 4.79, -0.472]} scale={[0.097, 1, 1]} />
      <instancedMesh args={[nodes.Roundcube004.geometry, materials.PaletteMaterial001, 6]} instanceMatrix={nodes.Roundcube004.instanceMatrix} />
    </group>
  )
}

useGLTF.preload('/room-transformed.glb')
```

Why is it that almost all my component has the same error, is it something to do with the libraries and modules i am using? Is it something deprecated? Or is it how i am exporting the blender?